# ASP MVC Route Config - The resource cannot be found error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm newbie in asp mvc, currently, my demo project structure like this:

```
Areas -- Comment -- Controller -- HomeController
                               -- ManageController
Controller -- HomeController
          |-- CommentController
                 |____ PostMsg
                 |____ DeleteMsg
Views -- Home
     |     |--- Index.cshtml
     |-- Comment
           |--- PostMsg.cshtml
           |--- DeleteMsg.cshtml
```

When I browsing url like :

```
http://localhost/Comment/Manage/ --> return view successfully
http://localhost/Comment/PostMsg --> error "The resource cannot be found."
```

Anyone have any idea why asp mvc doesn't resolve my controller :-(

here is my global.asax.cs route config:

```
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "Demo.Web.Controllers" }
            );
```

here is my area registration route config:

```
        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Comment_default",
                "Comment/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "Demo.Web.Areas.Comment.Controllers" }
            );
        }
```

Problem : Comment/PostMsg url was resolved as an Controller in Comment Area

Goal : Comment/PostMsg url was resolved as an Action of CommentController

Any help would be appreciated :-)

**ISSUE RESOLVED**, edit area registration route config (work around):

```
        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Comment_default",
                "Comment/PostMsg",
                new { controller = "Comment", action = "PostMsg", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "Demo.Web.Controllers" }
            );

            context.MapRoute(
                "Comment_default",
                "Comment/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "Demo.Web.Areas.Comment.Controllers" }
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you have action **Index ** in **PostMsgController** of **Demo.Web.Areas.Comment.Controllers**? as i understand you havn't

**UPDATE 1**

from your code i thnik that /Comment/PostMsg - could be your action Index of controller PostMsgController in Demo.Web.Areas.Comment.Controllers

**UPDATE 2**

than you should do

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Comment_default",
    "Comment/PostMsg",
    new { controller = "Comment", action = "PostMsg", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "Demo.Web.Controllers" }
);
```

Comment: of cos I have the PostMsg action :-( and the PostMsg.cshtml in Views\Comment\ folder :-(

Comment: sorry, in Demo.Web.Areas.Comment.Controllers

Comment: I don't want to push PostMsg action inside Areas.Comment.Controller.HomeController. My goal is call PostMsg action in CommentController :-)

Comment: than you should register your area later! OR make diff rule

Comment: Yes, that my problem, asp mvc detect PostMsg as an controller in Comment Areas :-( (I want it detect PostMsg as an action of Comment Controller)

Comment: see update, if it help, than vote up
and check when you register your areas, it could be also conflict of same name controller in area and in general folder

Comment: also i reccomend **rename** your **HomeController** in **area**

Comment: also check WHEN you register areas

Comment: yup, this work around idea solved my problem, thanks for pointing me the right way.